# How to use fo:leader with Apache FOP?

Tags: java, printing, formatting, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am not able to use fo:leader with Apache FOP. My requirement is to add trailing dots after some text. I am using the following but it is not working:

```
<fo:block font-family="Liberation Serif" font-size="8pt" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" color="#000000" text-align-last="justify">0000: Net Income
       <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" leader-length="100%" font-size="8pt"/>
</fo:block>
```

But the output is not    0000: Net Income ............

Instead the output is    0000:

Also if the text wraps then how do I align the leader dots with the last line of the text? This happens in "Right To Left" mode for Arabic language. The leader dots show after the first line instead of the last.

Answer (score 1):

Change `fo:leader/@laeder-length` from `leader-length="100%"` to `leader-length.maximum="100%"`.

Then you can get the desired result:

[image: FOP formatting result]

Comment: Thanks tmakita. How do I align the leader dots to the bottom of the text. If the text wraps then the dots show on top instead of the bottom of the text.

Comment: In my testing, the fo:leader is located at the bottom of line. Download and check the PDF from here. https://1drv.ms/b/s!AkbL99fLhxKUh-1RL5qDmWJd-NAFGw?e=SvXedd

Comment: For Arabic language I need to show the dots before the text. In that case the dots appear on top if the the text wraps, like this:

.... 0000: Net 
              Income

I want it like this:
    0000: Net
................ Income

Comment: @user1423596 It is better to submit your question with the FO example in another post. You didn't mention about Arabic in this post at all. The prerequisite has been changed.